# Calling serializer's extract methods

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to overwrite either extractSingle or extractSave from the DS.RESTSerializer. What to do after this? Do I call those method in my controller to retrieve json data? What is the correct way to retrieve the datas from calling those methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Ember uses your serializer, according to convention, you never explicitly call those methods.  They will be called by Ember directly.  The adapter will make the REST call and then use the object's serializer to extract arrays and/or single objects.

The objects extracted will then be put into the store (either inserting or replacing existing objects according to ID).  You will then retrieve them in your `Route` by calling `store.find('modeltype')`.

Comment: What if I don't want a model for this data and just want, for example, to push it into an array and forget about it afterward?

Comment: If that is the case, you don't need a serializer.  The `RESTSerializer` is meant to be used in conjunction with Ember Data.  Simply use `Ember.$.ajax` (or whatever method you choose) and process the result as needed.

Comment: thank you! I was wondering about using plain old ajax, gonna try this and update.

Comment: Glad that helped!  An acceptance of my answer would be great if you feel it answers your question...